# Successive differentiation

Tags: derivatives

Find the value of $y_n$  for $x = 0 $,when  $$ y = e^{(a sin^{-1}(x))}$$.
In the my book  its already solved the problem is that I don't understand after a certain point ,the steps.
After solving we have

$$(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}-(n^2+a^2)y_n = 0 $$
Putting x = 0
 $$(y_{n+2})_0 = (n^2+a^2) (y_n)_0$$
Replacing n by n-2,we get similarly
 $$(y_{n})_0 = ((n-2)^2+a^2) (y_{n-2})_0 $$

After this point /step I don't understand anymore ,here is the rest which I want you people to explain me how and why its done (which is actually my question) ...

$$(y_{n})_0 = ((n-2)^2+a^2) ((n-4)^2+a^2) (y_{n-4})_0 $$

Also   $(y_1)_0 = a, (y_2)_0 = a^2$ (the first and second derivative at 0 )

Thus  $$(y_{n})_0 = ((n-2)^2+a^2) ((n-4)^2+a^2)......(4^2 +a^2)(2^2-a^2)a^2$$ ,if n is even

and  $$(y_{n})_0 = ((n-2)^2+a^2) ((n-4)^2+a^2)......(3^2 +a^2)(1^2-a^2)a^2$$ ,if n is odd

---

I think the last one should be
$$(y_{n})_0 = ((n-2)^2+a^2) ((n-4)^2+a^2)......(3^2 +a^2)(1^2-a^2)a$$ ,if n is odd

but what I wrote above is what given in my book

Thanks

Comment: What is the notation $y_n$?

Comment: It's the n th derivative of y.

Comment: Well this problem is solved in another forum here is the link
http://www.mathisfunforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=383634